# Permanently set enviroment variables on UNIX SLES12

Tags: linux, oracle, unix, environment-variables

For the Oracle installation I have to change the environment variables.

For example, I tried the following:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/<path>/oracle/product/<version>/<home>
```

In the same session it works, but when I open a new terminal the values are gone again.

I also changed the `/etc/environment` and the `~/.bash_profile` files with no luck.

For the `.bash_profile` file, I also have the source `~/.bash_profile` command

Thanks for your help in advance.

(I need the environment variables for using sqlplus on Linux. If anyone has a similar experience, I'd love to hear from you.)

Comment: I solve the problem by restart the VM. but thanks for everyone trying to helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Create a script in `/etc/profile.d/`, for example ora.sh:

```sh
# cat /etc/profile.d/ora.sh
export TMOUT=172800
export SQLPATH=/s
export TNS_ADMIN=/opt/oracle/TNS_ADMIN
export ORACLE_PATH=/s
export ORACLE_BASE=/opt/oracle
export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/ora19
```

Here I set

- TMOUT - for SSH session
- SQLPATH and ORACLE_PATH - for scripts directory for use in sqlplus
- TNS_ADMIN - where stored all my TNS settings (I have multiple tns_names and use `IFILE` to include them)
- ORACLE_BASE and ORACLE_HOME - for oracle base and current oracle home

Comment: What triggers the script? I'm not so familiar with Linux scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really like messing with profile.d.  I make the changes in my .bash_profile.  Unfortunately, you didn't really show *exactly* what you did in your .bash_profile.  Here's the relevant portion of mine.  Note that I rely on oraenv to set my PATH, ORACLE_HOME, and ORACLE_BASE

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# 3 Aug 2012 - Ed Stevens
#   - replaced hard coded settings of ORACLE_* vars with use of oraenv
#     utility.
export ORACLE_TERM=xterm
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:$PATH
export ORACLE_SID=cdb
export ORAENV_ASK=NO
. oraenv
unset ORAENV_ASK


PS1="\n\D{%F} \t\n\u:\$ORACLE_SID\$ "
export PS1
```

A more 'textbook' version:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:$PATH
export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
export ORACLE_HOME=/$ORACLE_BASE/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "For the .bash_profile file, I also have the source ~/.bash_profile command"  If you are saying that you placed

```
~/.bash_profile command
```

in your .bash_profile, that seems to me that you created an infinite loop, by asking the file to execute itself.

Comment: 1. the oraenv file in the Oracle-Bin-directory is also still for the terminal session. 2. The funny part was, that there wasn't even a ~/.bash_profile file, so i just created one, just to test if it works or not. I even put in the export lines like you wrote it. I hoped, that it get reconized by the sqlplus and it is set globally, didnt work so well.

Comment: Again, you show no detail, no actual file contents, no actual commands and results. Therefor "didn't work so well" is totally meaningless.  I can't suggest corrections to what I cannot see.